# Changing Button visibility onClick with editText activity

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I have a button and two editTexts.
I was wondering if anyone could tell me how I could check the editTexts activity;
if both editTexts are empty the button is visible, may be transparent but un-clickable.
Does anyone know the code to change visibility or make it un-clickable?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is to listen to your edittext by using [addTextChangedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener%28android.text.TextWatcher%29) and disable or hide your button.

```
    yourEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yourEditTextId);

    yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

      public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

      public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

      public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        // check the count here and hide your button in response either by hiding it or disabling it.
        button.setEnabled(false); 
      }
     });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've learned quite a lot since posting this question. I'm still beginning to learn Java. Again, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

you should use `setEnabled(false);` on your button to make it not clickable. use instead `setEnabled(true);` to get the opposite behaviour

Answer (score 0):

You can set your button unclickable as--
From the xml:

```
android:enabled="false"
```

From the code:

```
button.setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Use opposite behavior for the opposite case :)

Answer (score 0):

you should use **addTextChangedListener** as Ahmad Kayyali mentioned.
and to toggle **Visibility**, as you asked, use:

```
button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```